# Stored procedure filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Have procedure where I count provider phases payment, phase 6 has 3 providers let's call **A,B,C** I want count * phases payments but in phase 6 i don't want count B (id=101)provider payments, i write select :

```
select phase , count(*) as countPhases
from  dbo.auth a
inner join dbo.providers p ON a.provider_id = p.serno 
where (date between @from_date and @to_date) and (provider_id <> 101 and phase <> 6 )
group by phase
```

but it dont filter how i want **(provider_id <> 101 and phase <> 6 )** , please help me

Comment: Do you want to ignore all records which have `phase = 6`? What I mean is are you sure you need an AND over there?

Comment: i need ignore phase = 6 for provider_id = 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
where (date between @from_date and @to_date)
      and (phase <> 6
           or (phase=6 and provider_id <> 101))
```